# Firebase doesn't return ordered result

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to take the result from Firebase ordered by "sortDate" but the actual one is randomly ordered. I would like to get the data in this order: [hip, chest, back, waist]. Here is my code:

```
final DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("parts");

        final DatabaseReference user = myRef.child("slavi");
        user.orderByChild("sortDate");

        user.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
```

And I added an image of the firebase structure.

[image]

Comment: I think the mistake here is that you are adding time stamp as a string in your data. Try to use a number and it should work.

Comment: Ishank Gulati, thank you for the suggestion but it's still the same even after changing sortDate to be of long type

Comment: Can you post another screenshot of console after the update?

Comment: It's looking good. It it still isn't working try and replace DatabaseReference by Query but I am not really sure if this will work.

Comment: Just trying to get your question clear. Do you want the data you get back from firebase to be ordened or the data stored inside firebase to be ordened?

Comment: It's clear: "I would like to take the result from Firebase ordered by "sortDate"

Comment: Great, in that case i suggest you also show the result you are getting. Right now all you show in your question is the actual data inside firebase.

Comment: From the question: but the actual one is randomly ordered. I would like to get the data in this order: [hip, chest, back, waist]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`dataSnapshot.getChildren()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getChildren()) with [`ValueEventListener`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ValueEventListener). It will loop through the child snapshots in-order. It has similar semantics to JS SDK [`DataSnapshot.forEach`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#forEach) which has more detailed documentation.

```
for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    Log.i(TAG, "test " + child.getValue());
}
```

Or you can use [`ChildEventListener`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ChildEventListener) which calls `onChildAdded` with each child snapshot in-order

```
    user.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "test2 " + dataSnapshot.getValue());
                }

                ...
```

UPDATE:

I see your problem. You are not attaching the listener to the query reference.

```
user.orderByChild("sortDate");

user.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
```

Should be:

```
   user.orderByChild("sortDate").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
```

Comment: I use exactly dataSnapshot.getChildren() and they are not in order

Comment: No, I am attaching a listener but did it in two steps: user.orderBy..., user.addListener. It's exactly the same result.

Comment: I even can do it like that: FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                    .child("parts")
                    .child("slavi").orderByChild("sortDate")
                    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
but I make it more clear by separating different parts.

Answer (score 0):

When you call any of Firebase's querying method (`orderBy...`, `startAt()`, `equalAt()`, etc) you get back a new `Query` object. Your code doesn't keep a reference to that query object.

To fix this:

```
 final DatabaseReference user = myRef.child("slavi");
 Query query = user.orderByChild("sortDate");

 query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
              System.out.println(userSnapshot.getKey());
          }
```